# Playing audio file in Swift using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, avfoundation, avplayer

I have a very simple method for playing an mp3 audio file in Swift using `AVPlayer`.

The problem is, it seems too simple. For example, in cases where there is an issue with the playback, an issue with the file, an issue with the device audio, how can the playback fail gracefully instead of the app crashing?

Or is the below playback code safe?

```
import UIKit

import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer:AVPlayer!

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        audioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myResourceFileName", ofType: "mp3")!))
        audioPlayer.play()

    }

}
```

Comment: Test pathForResource using if let statement. Do not do force unwrap.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try "Do" and "Catch"?

```
do {let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myResourceFileName", ofType: "mp3")
     let soundUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
     try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundUrl)
         audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()            
   } catch let err as NSError {
       print(err.debugDescription)
   }
```

and place
    audioPlayer.play()
at a function where you want to play.